# I have three lists with a vector of values, how can I put all three list's values at the same index into an existing dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

A fully reproducible example. The problem is now the new columns created is in c() of all the values instead of each value being in it's individual row.

```
date = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)

productB = rep("B",48)
productB = rep("B",48)
productA = rep("A",48)
productA = rep("A",48)

subproducts1=rep("1",48)
subproducts2=rep("2",48)
subproductsx=rep("x",48)
subproductsy=rep("y",48)

b1 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b2 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b3 <-c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b4 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
```

Created the dataframe below

```
dfone <- data.frame("date"= rep(date,4),
                "product"= c(rep(productB,2),rep(productA,2)),
                "subproduct"= 
c(subproducts1,subproducts2,subproductsx,subproductsy),
                "actuals"= c(b1,b2,b3,b4))

export_df <- split(dfone[1:4], dfone[3])

# Creation of data frames based off UNIQUE SUBPRODUCTS 
dummy_list <- split(dfone[1:4], dfone[3]) %>% lapply( function(x) 
x[(names(x) %in% c("date", "actuals"))])
dummy_list <-  lapply(dummy_list, function(x) { x["date"] <- NULL; x })


list_dfs <- list()
for (i in 1:length(unique(dfone$subproduct))) {
  #assign(paste0("df", i), as.data.frame(dummy_list[[i]]))
  list_dfs <-append(list_dfs,dummy_list[[i]])
}

combined_dfs <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE,  
by='date'), list(list_dfs))
```

Creating the time series

```
list_ts <- lapply(list_dfs, function(t) 
ts(t,start=c(2019,1),end=c(2021,6), frequency = 12)) %>%
  lapply( function(t) ts_split(t,sample.out=(0.2*length(t))))    # 
creates my train test split
list_ts <- do.call("rbind", list_ts)  #Creates a list of time series
```

Creating the models

```
model_tune_ses1 <- lapply(list_ts[1:(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x) 
forecast::forecast(ses(x,h=24,alpha=0.1))) 
model_tune_ses1 <- lapply(model_tune_ses1, "[",  c("mean"))

model_tune_ses2 <- lapply(list_ts[1:(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x) 
forecast::forecast(ses(x,h=24,alpha=0.2))) 
model_tune_ses2 <- lapply(model_tune_ses2, "[",  c("mean"))

model_trp_holt_mult <- lapply(list_ts[1:(length(list_ts)/2)], 
function(x)
  forecast::forecast( HoltWinters(x,seasonal="multiplicative"),h=24))

model_trp_holt_mult <- lapply(model_trp_holt_mult, "[",  c("mean"))
lst1 <- do.call(Map, c(f = cbind, mget(ls(pattern = 'model_'))))

export_df1 <- Map(cbind, export_df, lst1)


export_df1 <- bind_rows(export_df1, .id = "date")
```

I've deleted the other edits to save a lot more space.

Edit2:

```
export_df1[[6]]
[[1]]
      Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      
Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
2021 6.508872 4.639274 4.678671 4.626766 5.327353 6.890269 6.640483 
6.164311 5.317675 6.152747 5.963053 5.243159
2022 6.517052 4.645104 4.684550 4.632579 5.334046 6.898923 6.648823 
6.172052 5.324353 6.160472 5.970540 5.249740

    export_df1[[6]]
[[2]]
      Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      
Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
2021 6.508872 4.639274 4.678671 4.626766 5.327353 6.890269 6.640483 
6.164311 5.317675 6.152747 5.963053 5.243159
2022 6.517052 4.645104 4.684550 4.632579 5.334046 6.898923 6.648823 
6.172052 5.324353 6.160472 5.970540 5.249740
```

Instead of having each row in my dataframe as a list of all of those values, I want the column in the form like below.

```
export_df1$actuals
  [1] 4.729682 4.573595 7.338069 4.742559 5.853501 3.167612 6.305137 
5.879437 4.571004 5.367115 5.127305 4.552428 5.843000 4.060205 4.125869 
4.190687
[17] 4.894595 6.454123 4.686262 4.196005 7.289879 6.206924 6.191610
```

6.100175 4.769656 4.829249 5.287280 4.425435 5.158180 4.402173 0.000000
0.000000 etc

Comment: I've updated the post and yes that is true, so this is where I wanted to have a vector of 0's added on before the output of a vector match the length of 48 for each part of my dataframe. Or we can leave the 0's as null that should be fine, but it has to be on the bottom half, not the first half of the column so like (0,0,0,0,........the output from a list from the column)

Comment: Please check mmy update

Comment: Going to test on my real code to see what happens, but on the dummy code this works perfectly. You are genius

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help. Was wondering how you got so good at R, some of these functions I've never heard before. Any tips/books to read?

Comment: I would say this is how you will learn :=) i.e learning the hard way.  On a serious note, there are lots of books online you can read, but in programming, it is the practice and debugging by yourself improves the skill.  It may sound hard at first, but believe me, it will be easier in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could get all the 'list_ts_ses' objects in a `list`

```
lst1 <- do.call(Map, c(f = cbind, mget(ls(pattern = 'list_ts_ses'))))
export_df1 <- Map(cbind, export_df, lst1)
```

#### Update

```
out <- Map(function(x, y) {x[colnames(y)] <- sapply(y, 
    function(u) c(rep(0, nrow(x) - length(u)), u)); x}, export_df, lst1)
```

-checking the structure

```
 str(out)
List of 4
 $ 1:'data.frame':  48 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ date               : Date[1:48], format: "2019-01-01" "2019-02-01" "2019-03-01" "2019-04-01" ...
  ..$ product            : chr [1:48] "B" "B" "B" "B" ...
  ..$ subproduct         : chr [1:48] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
  ..$ actuals            : num [1:48] 5.57 5.16 5.33 4.15 4.29 ...
  ..$ model_trp_holt_mult: num [1:48] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ model_tune_ses1    : num [1:48] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ model_tune_ses2    : num [1:48] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 2:'data.frame':  48 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ date               : Date[1:48], format: "2019-01-01" "2019-02-01" "2019-03-01" "2019-04-01" ...
  ..$ product            : chr [1:48] "B" "B" "B" "B" ...
  ..$ subproduct         : chr [1:48] "2" "2" "2" "2" ...
  ..$ actuals            : num [1:48] 6.5 5.07 4.06 6.9 3.72 ...
  ..$ model_trp_holt_mult: num [1:48] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ model_tune_ses1    : num [1:48] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ model_tune_ses2    : num [1:48] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ x:'data.frame':  48 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ date               : Date[1:48], format: "2019-01-01" "2019-02-01" "2019-03-01" "2019-04-01" ...
  ..$ product            : chr [1:48] "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
  ..$ subproduct         : chr [1:48] "x" "x" "x" "x" ...
  ..$ actuals            : num [1:48] 5.21 6.51 2.42 4.8 3.62 ...
  ..$ model_trp_holt_mult: num [1:48] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ model_tune_ses1    : num [1:48] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ model_tune_ses2    : num [1:48] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ y:'data.frame':  48 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ date               : Date[1:48], format: "2019-01-01" "2019-02-01" "2019-03-01" "2019-04-01" ...
  ..$ product            : chr [1:48] "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
  ..$ subproduct         : chr [1:48] "y" "y" "y" "y" ...
  ..$ actuals            : num [1:48] 5.01 5.39 5.23 5.43 3.99 ...
  ..$ model_trp_holt_mult: num [1:48] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ model_tune_ses1    : num [1:48] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ model_tune_ses2    : num [1:48] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

#### data

```
export_df <- list(data.frame(col1 = 1:24, col2 = 25:48), data.frame(col1 = 1:24, col2 = 25:48), data.frame(col1 = 1:24, col2 = 25:48))
list_ts_ses <- list(ts(rnorm(24), frequency = 12, start = c(2021, 1)),ts(rnorm(24), frequency = 12, start = c(2021, 1)), ts(rnorm(24), frequency = 12, start = c(2021, 1)) )
list_ts_ses1 <- list(ts(rnorm(24), frequency = 12, start = c(2021, 1)),ts(rnorm(24), frequency = 12, start = c(2021, 1)), ts(rnorm(24), frequency = 12, start = c(2021, 1)) )
list_ts_ses2 <- list(ts(rnorm(24), frequency = 12, start = c(2021, 1)),ts(rnorm(24), frequency = 12, start = c(2021, 1)), ts(rnorm(24), frequency = 12, start = c(2021, 1)) )
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see the comments earlier, I've been playing around with my data, and I made an edit above. I know I need to have a vector of 24 vectors before all of my outputs so something like ( c(rep(0,24), unlist(list_ts_ses[[4]]))). list_ts_ses[1],etc,etc needs to all go into export_df[1] and vice versa

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear. I have x lists with a vector of values. We can say we have 3 lists. Iist1[[3]], list2[[3]],list3[[3]]. I want the index of 3 for all three lists, added into my list of dataframe/tibbles at export_df[[3]] as new columns. So from my edit1 in the original post the columns should be tibble 48x 7. My values of list1[[3]] are only length 24, sand I need to add a vector of 24 0's before those values so it matches the row length of 48 in the export_df[[1]]

Comment: I believe this is almost what I want. export_df1[[1]]$list_ts_ses, for example returns another list of 48 values and not just a vector of values length 48. I do want 24 0's before my list[[1]] output so it equals 48.

Comment: I'm going to play with the sample data you provided, and make it clear exactly what I want from the output. I'll update you tonight when I'm free. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I've played around with your code and mine and found the problem, see the new edit 2.1 and edit 3

Comment: In edit 2.1 i am showing the output of list1_1, which is what I want i.e a list with elements of values. In edit 3.1,( MY CODE) I am showing the output of the format of a list, which is a list of lists containing values. Is there anyway I can unlist the list so my model_arima becomes like list1_1? I have 100 lists in my code, only 3 in this example.

Comment: @chriswang123 do you need `do.call(c, model_arima)` or `lapply(model_arima, function(x) x$mean)`

Comment: @chriswang123 can you try that

Comment: I have 100 lists right now, is there a way I can apply it to all of them at the same time and store it as a new object with the same variable name?

Comment: @chriswang123 Do you have `model_arima` stored in a `list` or there are 100s of model_arima

Comment: There is 100's of model_... objects in my environment

Comment: @chriswang123 Just do `lapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'model_arima')), yourfun)` where yourfun is the code, we used

Comment: lapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'model_')), do.call(c, model_arima)) doesn't work? Also I want model_ as a pattern, so how do i apply yourfun

Comment: Here, you need `lapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'model_')), function(x) do.call(c, x))`

Comment: i.e. we are constructing a lambda function

Comment: I see, so now how do I add this to my export_df? The output is a list, but the some of the elements are double 96 and another list of 4 with 24 elements each.

Comment: @chriswang123 right now, I am confused.  I was thinking that you have a single list of export_df and the model_arima list.  NOw, with multiple model_arima list, do you have multiple export_df list as well

Comment: The original plan was to add each OUTPUT into it's respective export_df[[1]]. In edit 2.1, the code works exactly how i'd want it too. The problem was getting my 100 lists into the same format as list1_1 (see edit 3 how 1 of my 100 lists look) so i can try the original code in edit 2.1

Comment: @chriswang123 my question is that `export_df` is one object or multiple objects

Comment: @chriswang123 i.e. if you already updated the export_df from one of your model_arima object.  where does the second object updates

Comment: Export_df is ONE object and it's a list of dataframes. I want it so each of my 100 lists list1[[1]] can go into export_df[[1]], etc.. which is edit 2.1's code. The problem is the lists how they are in my code are a list of lists containing values, which is why I asked if I could change the format.

Comment: Maybe this is easier, if I run the code you do without modifying the structure of the list in edit 3, I get my dataframe in the format I want, but the NEW COLUMNS created have values that  are objects<ts> not the actual value itsself

Comment: @chriswang123 so you have only a single `export_df` object and the first list elemeent should get the result of `lst1 <- do.call(Map, c(f = cbind, mget(ls(pattern = 'list_ts_ses'))))` sorry, it is so confusing to me without a reproducible example

Comment: Okay I can go create it.

Comment: @chriswang123 thanks, a reproducible example would help in testing.  Otherwise,what I think about your structure is different

Comment: I've created the reproducible example in the edit

Comment: @chriswang123 where is `ses` function from

Comment: @chriswang123 i was able to get it working.  what is the expected after the last code

Comment: Notice how each value in the new columns created are a vector of values. I want the vector's values to go down the row, and not stored as many of the same vectors

Comment: @chriswang123 right now, it is a list of columns i..e `$ model_tune_ses1:List of 48
  ..$ : Time-Series  from 2021 to 2023: 4.87 4.87 4.87 4.87 4.87 ...
  ..$ : Time-Series  from 2021 to 2023: 4.87 4.87 4.87 4.87 4.87 ...
  ..$ : Time-Series  from 2021 to 2023: 4.87 4.87 4.87 4.87 4.87 ...
  ..$ : Time-Series  from 2021 to 2023: 4.87 4.87 4.87 4.87 4.87 ...`

Comment: If you open export_df1 as the object from the environment, notice how the values are stored as c(5.32,5.32,5.32...) i want those values to go down in each row instead of being in a vector in each row

Comment: Isn't those list elements repeated

Comment: Yes, but i can't export to Excel like this, because of the format of the column values of those new model_ columns. Let me create a model with varying elements in a vector

Comment: @chriswang123 if you check the `str(export_df1[[1]])` i.e. for first element, there are `model_tune_ses1`, `model_tune_ses2 et as list elements .  each with 48 elementss. what do you expect in that output

Comment: I added a new model, check above edit we can base our discussion on, the model_trp_holt_mult. If we do export_df$model_trp_holt_multi, we see at every 48 rows there is a new vector. For row's 1-48 I want to unpack the vector so each observation at row 1-48 is each value at index in one vector